# What is an alternative to 'display: inline' in firefox?

Tags: html, css

I have created a responsive dynamic element in HTML and CSS. Please check the below screenshot to see the general view of the element. This contains the title and an absolute positioned shape.
[image]

Below is the code line you can refer

```css
.main-heading {
  font-size: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline;
}

.main-heading .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-heading .after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #FDDB3A;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 12px;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="main-heading">
  <span class="content">Reasons Why People Choose Us</span>
  <span class="after"></span>
</h2>
```

As you can see in the snippet,

> the after shape is perfectly fitting the width of the last line

and this is because of the `display: inline`. But unfortunately, this misbehaves in firefox. Below is a screenshot in firefox browser (stretch the window with and see the problem)

What is an alternative I can try to work the same in all modern browsers?
[image]

> **I would like to get this done in only HTML and CSS, NO JAVASCRIPT.
> Because this is a custom widget created in ELEMENTOR with style
> controls.**

Comment: ypu want only the last line ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were no proper answers found, I managed to write CSS only targetting firefox as below,

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .main-heading span {
      display: inline-block;
  }
}
```